# Example of buffer usage

Tags: performance, video, stream, connection, buffer

If I have a slower connection to the Internet that a video stream requires, how is actually the way that the buffer will work?

Answer (score 1):

A buffer is meant to take care of sudden, but short drops in the connection speed. Buffering cannot prevent the loss of streaming data if the average speed it too low.